# Searching access database with keyword

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, search

I am using the following SQL query to search database.

`string sql = "SELECT [identifier] FROM [information] WHERE [identifier] LIKE '" + identifier + "%'"`;

when I enter "m" to search "Microsoft" it finds Microsoft but if i enter "o" it doesn't find Microsoft.

How can i change SQL so that it finds everything containing that particular word?

Comment: Careful about SQL injection vulnerability here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it does not search for string *Microsoft* when you search for letter `o` is because your condition filters based on the starting character.

This condition,

```
... WHERE [identifier] LIKE 'o%'
```

means *..give me all strings that starts with character `o`*. If you want to search for a string that `contains` character `o`, you should wrap it with `%%`. example,

```
... WHERE [identifier] LIKE '%o%'
```

As a sidenote, you should be parameterizing the values to avoid `SQL Injection`.

Try this code snippet:

```
string connStr = "connection string here";
string content = string.Format("{0}{1}{0}", "%", identifier);
string sqlStatement = "SELECT [identifier] FROM [information] WHERE [identifier] LIKE ?";
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
{
    using(SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand())
    {
        comm.Connection = conn;
        comm.CommandText = sqlStatement;
        comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@content", content);

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            // other codes
        }
        catch(SqlException e)
        {
            // do something with the exception
            // do not hide it
            // e.Message.ToString()
        }
    }
}
```

For proper coding

- use `using` statement for proper object disposal
- use `try-catch` block to properly handle exceptions

Comment: i tried this but not working  "SELECT [identifier] FROM [information] WHERE [identifier] LIKE '%" + identifier + "%'";

Answer (score 0):

```
string sql = "SELECT [identifier] FROM [information] WHERE INSTR([identifier]," + identifier +") != 0 ";
```

[ACCESS function INSTR()](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/access-help/instr-function-HA001228857.aspx)